# Swiftでアプリ全体で利用できる定数は、「どこに」「どのように」書くと良いか？

Tags: swift

ざっと思いつく方法としては、
・ENUMを使う
・Defineクラスをつくる
です。

どのようにするのが、良さそうでしょうか？

Comment: マイナス票がいくつか付いていますが、質問の意図や懸念事項を詳しく説明すると、よいかと思います。想定している定数の内容や、考えているEnum/クラスのコード例など。英語版の類似の質問[「Swiftで定数を定義するクラスの書き方は?」](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25196051/20226)が、質問を書く参考になると思います。(英語の内容ではなく、文章の量やコード例を含めているところに注目)

Comment: ヘルプセンターの[良い質問をするには？](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)の記事も参考になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

専用のクラスを作るのであれば、structを使うほうが良いかと思います。

Swiftのclassは値を保持するクラス定数を持つことが出来ませんが、structであれば可能なので。

```
// 問題なくコンパイルできる
struct ConstStruct {
    static let nameMax = 32
    static let imageMargin: CGFloat = 10.0
    static let defaultName = "NO NAME"
}

// コンパイルエラーになる
class ConstClass {
    static let nameMax = 32
    static let imageMargin: CGFloat = 10.0
    static let defaultName = "NO NAME"
}
```

Comment: クラスのタイププロパティはreadonlyとして宣言できるので、事実上定数と同じように扱えます。リファレンスを読みましょう。

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID265

Answer (score 1):

「let」を付与すれば、なんでも定数として扱えると思います。
C言語の流儀を、いったん忘れないと、感覚的にしっくりこないかもしれませんね。

「どこに」に関しては、クラスや構造体などの実装の外側に、独立して、ということになろうかと。

Comment: マイナス票を入れた方: できればマイナスの理由をコメントしていっていただけると、回答の改善につながりますし、回答を参考にしようとしている人にも何がよくないかも分かるので役立ちます。

Comment: 「なんでも定数として扱える」という点や「実装の外側に独立して」という点を具体的に説明するコード例があると、より役立つ回答になるかと思います。(実例がないと主観的意見にみえがちなので、マイナスが付いたのかなと推測しました)